# Use CSV to create documents

Tags: csv, database

I have a CSV file like this

```
Name, Number 
Apple, 5 
Oranges, 20 
Banana, 50
```

I have a latex template

```
\docementclass{article}
\begin{document}
I have [number] [Name]
\end{document}
```

I would like to populate fields from tables and generate one pdf file/page  for each row. How can I do this

Answer (score 4):

You can use the datatool package.

Assuming your csv file named data.csv:

```
\documentclass{article}
   
\usepackage{datatool}
  
\begin{document}
  
\DTLloaddb{list}{data.csv}
  
\DTLforeach{list}{%
\fruit=Name,\quantity=Number}{\newpage
I have \quantity{} \fruit.}
\end{document}
```

[datatool documentation](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf)